# React setState of object with boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy, setstate

I've looked for answers to this question online and while I've found various posts and articles relating to it I can't figure out why this doesn't work for me.

```
  setTimeout(()=> {
    let markerCopy = {...this.state.previousMarker}

    this.state.previousInfoWindow.close()
    this.state.previousMarker.setLabel(null)
    markerCopy.infowindow = false

    this.setState({
      previousMarker: {
        markerCopy,
      }
    })
  },50)
```

This is my latest attempt at a chunk of code which should make a copy of my `previousMarker` object which is contained in `this.state`, it then sets the boolean `infowindow` to `false` for that copy and finally should replace the `previousMarker` in state with that copy. Somewhere along the way this isn't working.

Previously I had been just using `this.state.previousMarker.infowindow = false`, but obviously this is mutating state directly and is frowned upon.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  setTimeout(() => {
  let markerCopy = { ...this.state.previousMarker };

  this.state.previousInfoWindow.close()
  this.state.previousMarker.setLabel(null)
  markerCopy.infowindow = false;
  this.setState({ previousMarker: markerCopy }, () =>
    console.log(this.state.previousMarker)
  );
}, 50);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help, also the console.log inside this.setState throws an error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, there was typo. Can you try this.setState({ previousMarker: markerCopy }). You can also see my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ojqjo1wzw5

Comment: Thanks Mahima, I looked at my code again and console logged a bunch of pieces of this function. It looks like my issue isn't with the state in the end. But your way did help and worked well, however it's a different issue after all!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out what was happening! I think the issue was the spread operator, which I thought I needed. The fix was this:

```
    let markerCopy = this.state.previousMarker

    markerCopy.infowindow = false

    this.setState({ previousMarker: markerCopy })
```

Thanks for the help people.